# How to delete the data of one state from the TIGER geocoder

Tags: postgis, tiger

I'm getting wrong values for the coordinates using the tiger geocoder.
I have some issues with this states because some missing values and I want to upload all the data again, but now it says 'xxxxxx' relations already exist. How can I delete those data and relations for a specific state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query to generate tables to delete and then run the query:

https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/Drop_State_Tables_Generate_Script.html

e.g.

```
SELECT drop_state_tables_generate_script('MA');
```

Will generate drop table statements for MA and then you just run the sql it generates.